# x86 assembly - get structure from an array with structures

Tags: arrays, data-structures, inline-assembly

I created an array with structures and I need to get the structure from the array using an index and a pointer to the array.

```
struct T{
    char a, b, c, d, e, f, g;
};

T CtiPrvekPole1(T *pole, int index){
    T result;
    _asm{
        mov eax, pole;
        mov ebx, index;
        mov eax, [eax + ebx * 8];
        mov result, eax;
    }
    return result;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    T struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4;

    struct1.a = 1;
    struct1.b = 2;
    struct1.c = 3;
    struct1.d = 4;
    struct1.e = 5;
    struct1.f = 6;
    struct1.g = 7;

    struct2.a = 8;
    struct2.b = 9;
    struct2.c = 10;
    struct2.d = 11;
    struct2.e = 12;
    struct2.f = 13;
    struct2.g = 14;

    struct3.a = 15;
    struct3.b = 16;
    struct3.c = 17;
    struct3.d = 18;
    struct3.e = 19;
    struct3.f = 20;
    struct3.g = 21;

    struct4.a = 22;
    struct4.b = 23;
    struct4.c = 24;
    struct4.d = 25;
    struct4.e = 26;
    struct4.f = 27;
    struct4.g = 28;

    T pole1[] = { struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4 };

    T result = CtiPrvekPole1(pole1, 2);
    printf("Cti prvek pole1 : %c\n", result.b);

}
```

How should I get that struct? I used 8 bytes, because one structure has 7 bytes, so it should 8 bytes with aligment. Am I right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your thinking is correct, but your code is incorrect. You have:

```
T CtiPrvekPole1(T *pole, int index){
    T result;
    _asm{
        mov eax, pole;
        mov ebx, index;
        mov eax, [eax + ebx * 8];
        mov result, eax;
    }
    return result;
}
```

So you're moving an address (a pointer) into the first four bytes of memory that's occupied by `result`. You need to move the data.

The C code to do that would be:

```
T result;
result = pole[index];
return result;
```

That copies the 8 bytes from the array at `pole[index]` into `result`, and then returns the result.

In fact, you don't even need the `CtiPrvekPole1` method. You could just write:

```
T pole1[] = { struct1, struct2, struct3, struct4 };
T result = pole1[2];
```

If you really want to do it in assembly language, then you have to get the source and destination addresses and copy. Here's one way to do it:

```
T CtiPrvekPole1(T *pole, int index){
    T result;
    _asm{
        mov eax, pole;
        mov ebx, index;
        mov ecx, [eax + ebx * 8];  // ecx = source address
        lea edx, result            // edx = destination address
        // copy first four bytes
        mov eax, [ecx]
        mov [edx], eax
        // copy next four bytes
        mov eax, [ecx+4]
        mov [edx+4], eax
    }
    return result;
}
```